# Shared file conflicts in package dependencies after Fedora 24 install

Tags: dependencies, fedora, skype

I recently installed Fedora 24 Workstation from the Live DVD and ever since have been getting a lot of software installation transaction errors due to file conflicts between the 32 bit and 64 bit versions when downloading dependent packages. A very similar question was asked here

[Shared doc files in dependencies causing transaction errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558676/shared-doc-files-in-dependencies-causing-transaction-errors/38565529)

but the answer has not helped me because when I run dnf upgrade my system is up to date.

The issue appears to be that the 64 bit versions on my system are older than the 32 bit versions that are trying to be installed.

For example, here are some dependency conflicts while trying to download Skype:

```
Error: Transaction check error:
file /usr/share/doc/glibc/NEWS from install of glibc-2.23.1-11.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64  
file /usr/share/licenses/libpng/LICENSE from install of libpng-2:1.6.26-1.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package libpng-2:1.6.21-2.fc24.x86_64
file /usr/share/man/man5/png.5.gz from install of libpng-2:1.6.26-1.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package libpng-2:1.6.21-2.fc24.x86_64
file /usr/share/doc/libgpg-error/NEWS from install of libgpg-error-1.24-1.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package libgpg-error-1.21-2.fc24.x86_64
file /usr/share/doc/libgpg-error/ChangeLog from install of libgpg-error-1.24-1.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package libgpg-error-1.21-2.fc24.x86_64
file /usr/share/doc/libgpg-error/AUTHORS from install of libgpg-error-1.24-1.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package libgpg-error-1.21-2.fc24.x86_64
....
```

Is there a way to force Fedora to download the latest versions of the 64 bit packages to match the latest 32 bit versions that are available?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system is up to date before you run the installation — that's usually what causes this. You can try `dnf --refresh update` to make sure it's not a local caching problem.